# Increase the size of a column in ZK

Tags: java

I want to increase the size of column in zk grid in case of adding columns in same line. Doing this after two columns next columns are added with smaller length. But I have called  layout.resize(); , I want that all columns will be added with defined size/length and the layout should be auto expanded with scroll. my code is pure java based on Zk.  Some of the code is:

```
Borderlayout layout = new Borderlayout();
Center center = new Center();
center.setFlex(true);
center.appendChild(grid);           
layout.appendChild(center);         
layout.resize();
formComponent = layout;
grid.setSizedByContent(true);
treePanel.getTree().addEventListener(Events.ON_SELECT, this);

//------------------------//
///here appends a new child////
Div div = new Div();
div.setAlign("right");
Label label = editor.getLabel();        
div.appendChild(label);
if (label.getDecorator() != null)
div.appendChild(label.getDecorator());             
row.appendChild(div);
//-------------------------------//
```

I have googled but found that 'grid.setSizedByContent(true)' works, but it works for .zul file. I can't use it in my java code for grid. Can anyone help me?